# iTunes playlists won't sort by Name anymore

Tags: itunes, music, playlist

I have recently had to upgrade to Windows 10, and with the 2 subsequent downloads of iTunes, I can no longer sort playlists by Name (Song title), which is what I prefer on my iPods. They USED to sort like the Songs list does (just click on Name and voila). Now I get fancy, multi-coloured lists I can't read or manipulate in any way. Not user-friendly at all. Help!

If I hadn't just had to completely re-create all playlists; all ratings, and reinstall all music into iTunes with the change, I'd be a lot more patient, but this is already a 6-month project to get back to where I was before.

Answer (score 1):

Found [here:](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7860331)

> When displaying your playlist, hopefully you see something like this.
>   If you do not, while viewing the playlist, use iTunes' menu to choose
>   View > View As > Songs
>
> [image]
>
> Then in the header row that says "Name ... Time ... Artist ...",
>   choose the field you wish to sort on and click that header button.

Answer (score 0):

The layout will be different on Windows, as the menus are inside the app itself [accessed by pressing  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  if not already visible] but the method is the same...

View Menu > View As > Songs
Then you can click any column header to sort on that column [current sort on Title highlighted with the red square].

[image]

Comment: Often this does not work. Instead of being able to move songs within a playlist all I get is a blue frame around the entire playlist (song view).